# Very low external microphone volume in Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

As the following picture shows, I have set the microphone volume to the maximum possible, but the volume recorded is very low despite putting the microphone very close to my mouth and speaking loudly. I do not have this problem with the internal microphone. And this external microphone works properly under Windows.

[image: Volume Control]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but I just added a USB webcam to my Xubuntu 20.04 desktop system and used it for the first time on a Zoom call.  I kept manually setting the mic volume to 100% in the Pulseaudio volume control and then a few minutes later it was reset to a very low setting.  This kept happening repeatedly.  Any idea why the volume would auto-adjust downward and how to stop this?  This is with a Larmtek W5 webcam.  I'm posting here as it seems possibly related.